# Spring Integration - Wait for Condition Before Processing Message

Tags: spring-integration

I need to implement a spring integration flow where certain messages can only be processed when a certain condition becomes true i.e. these messages need to wait. However, I do not want to block the flow. Is there a component that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without the risk of loosing the data if the instance goes down, as the data will be kept in memory (you could try to store it temporarily and re-inject it in case of a VM crash).

There's an integration pattern that spring implements called *Aggregator* which can be used for exact this purpose (link to [pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Aggregator.html) and [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.M4/spring-integration-reference/html/aggregator.html))

You'll need to implement a `CorrelationStrategy` that tells spring how different messages are related to each other and a `ReleaseStrategy` that can tell spring when all the items required have arrived, and as such, they can continue.

I'll repeat this again, all of the in-flight data is kept in memory, so you'll have to figure out how to store and re-inject data after a shutdown/crash.

Comment: A message-store-backed (or queue-backed) channel can also be used for persistence and is less complicated than an aggregator.

Comment: How would that work if you're waiting for messages from 1+ queues and you need real time processing? (of course I mean near-real-time :D, otherwise we end up in a different type of problems).

Answer (score 1):

You can start/stop a polling consumer on a `QueueChannel` - while the poller is stopped, messages will accumulate in the channel and then consumed when the consumer is started.

You can either get a reference to the consumer by bean name and start/stop it or you can use a control-bus and send messages to it `"foo.start()"`.

The messages would be held in memory by default. If you need persistence you can add a message store or use a channel backed by JMS, RabbitMQ etc.